# Suppose $M$ is a compact manifold, and $B$ is a regular co-ordinate ball, is $M \setminus B$ compact?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, compactness

> Suppose $M$ is a compact topological $n$-dimensional manifold, and $B$ is a regular coordinate ball, is $M \setminus B$ compact?

I already know that $M \setminus B$ is a $n$-dimensional manifold with boundary, and $\partial (M \setminus B)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$

A quick example that I can think of is $ M = [0, 1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Then choose the regular coordinate ball $B = (0, 1) \subseteq M$, then we have $M \setminus B = \{0, 1\}$ which is clearly compact.

Another example is $M = \overline{\mathbb{B}^n}$ the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\mathbb{B}^n$ is a regular co-ordinate ball and $M \setminus \mathbb{B}^n = \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ which is compact.

It seems that the quoted assertion above is true. So how could I prove this, I don't think I can prove it directly from the definition of a compact topological space.

Comment: “I don't think I can prove it directly from the definition of a compact topological space.” You can, at least once you’ve got that B is open.

Comment: If your ball is open then its complement $M\setminus B$ is closed and then it is compact since a closed subset of a compact set is compact.

Comment: @palio Whoops, that was a blonde moment